# PHP switching pages from a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, case

I have the following PHP code:

```
//switch
if (isset($_GET['pg']))
    $pg = $_GET['pg'];

else{
    $pg = 'home';
    }

switch ($pg){
    case 'home':
        if (file_exists("pages/home.php")){
            include("pages/home.php");}
        break;

    case 'about':
        if (file_exists("pages/about.php")){
            include("pages/about.php");}
        else{include_once("error.php");}
        break;

    case 'products':
        if (file_exists("pages/products.php")){
            include("pages/products.php");}
        else{include_once("error.php");}
        break;

    case 'contact':
        if (file_exists("pages/contact.php")){
            include("pages/contact.php");}
        else{include_once("error.php");}
        break;


    default:
        if (file_exists("error.php")){
        include("error.php");}
}
?>
```

How can I do this switch by a MySQL query? I tried something like this, but unfortunately doesn't work:

```
$SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM pages";
$result = mysql_query($SQLquery);

switch ($pg){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    case $row['id']:
        include($row['id'].'.php');
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: why would you not do the filtering in mysql, e.g. `select * from pages where id=XXX` so you only get one record? there's absolutely **NO** point in sucking an entire table across to php and then throwing away all but one record.

Comment: You can't put a while inside a switch. Only case can be inner commands. Case x: should use constant value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot dynamically define switch statements at runtime. These control structures are parsed before the code is run and can't be altered later (correct me if I'm wrong).

I'd try something along the lines of this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['id'] == $pg){
        include($row['id'].'.php');
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** On second thought, the solution @Marc M posted as a comment on the question is way better. Do this:

```
$SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id='" . $pg ."';";
$result = mysql_query($SQLquery);

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    include($row['id'].'.php');
else
    include("error.php");
```

And since you hopefully have declared the MySQL column `id` as `UNIQUE`, you either get exaclty one row or your `"error.php"` file will be included.

Comment: How can i add a else statement? For old code if $pg doesn't exist was included error file. `default:
        if (file_exists("error.php")){
        include("error.php");}`